# How to Slide Div on Button click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a sliding form button like [this](http://www.groupon.com/subscriptions/new?division_p=), I am not familiar to JQuery please suggest.

**The Html :-**

```
<div id="introFormHome">
<form action="" method="">
    <div id="slideBox1" class="slideBox">
          Conferm Location <input type="text" value="" />
          <button class="slideNext">Continue</button>
    </div>
    <div id="slideBox2" class="slideBox">
          Area <input type="text" value="" />
          <button class="slideNext">Continue</button>
    </div>
    <div id="slideBox3" class="slideBox">
          Email Address <input type="text" value="" />
          <button class="slideNext">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**The Jquery :-**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('.slideNext').click(function() {
   $('.slideBox').animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#introFormHome');
    });
    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});
</script>
```

**The CSS :-**

```
.slideBox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 70%;
    top: 300px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
#slideBox1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#slideBox2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 150%;
}

#slideBox3 {
    background-color: red;
    left: 150%;
}
```

There the css, its working fine if i set to click the div .slideBox{} it slides but not with the above posted script.

Comment: What is wrong with your attempt? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Its not sliding.... if we set the whole div to slide than it does but not with the click of a button... :(

Comment: If your div slides OK without a click but does not slide with a click, then I think @PaparazzoKid has the answer. Use document.ready.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend positioning all the form elements evenly so that you only need to shift everything once per click. That makes your jQuery code much simpler. Using percentages to position your elements will also make things trickier. You may consider using fixed pixel positioning instead. At that point, your JS can be as simple as

```
$('.slideNext').click(function() {
   $('.slideBox').animate({
     left: '-=150px'
   }, 500);
});​
```

See this jsFiddle for an example of implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/5aFHk/

I decided to use anchor tags instead of buttons, but either should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no jQuery expert but I do know that you will want to wrap that jQuery function in document.ready, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slideNext').click(function() {
       $('.slideBox').animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#introFormHome');
    });
    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the CSS? Left will only work if you div is relatively or absolutely positioned. If you don't have it already, set this in your css:

```
.slideBox{position:absolute}
```

Depending on your layout, you may also want to set:

```
#introFormHome{position:relative}
```

Like PaparazzoKid says, you should also wrap your jQuery in :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       //jQuery code in here
})
```